# Labels disappear from jQuery Flot when scrolling right (with tick rotor)

Tags: jquery, flot

When I load the page, everything is ok. Nevertheless, when I scroll right (to show the next days), the ticks disappear. I use the tickrotor.js to rotate the ticks.

```
xaxis: {
                panRange: [0, null],
                mode: "categories",
                tickLength: 1,
                rotateTicks: 135,
                min: 0,
                max: 15,
                labelWidth: 30},
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Page load:

[image: page load]

Scroll:

[image: scroll]

```
series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.6,
                    align: "center"
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                panRange: [0, null],
                mode: "categories",
                tickLength: 1,
                rotateTicks: 135,
                min: 1,
                max: 25,
                labelWidth: 30
            },
            yaxis: {
                panRange: [0, null]
            },
            zoom: {
                interactive: false
            },
            pan: {
                interactive: true
            }
```

Comment: The `min / max` options could be the problem here. Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay ... :)
I am sorry but i did not succeed to set up the fiddle. Do you think you can help me without please ? 
Thank you ..